# Does SqlDataReader store everything as a String?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to pull data using a SqlDataReader, one column of which is in datetime.  I'd like to do something like this

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", connection); //connection is defined earlier
        SqlDataReader data = command.ExecuteReader();
        while(data.Read()){
             DateTime birthday = data["Birth"];
             list.Add(birthday);
        }
    }
```

Can I do this?  Or does SqlDataReader return strings, in which case I'd have to create a new DateTime object using that string?

Thanks,
-S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SqlDataReader returns data as strongly-typed objects - just call the right method, e.g.:

data.GetDateTime(ordinal)

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
DateTime birthday = data.GetDateTime(data.GetOrdinal("Birth"));
```

SqlDataReader has a [whole bunch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods.aspx) of strongly-typed Get*() methods.

Comment: The GetDateTime method only takes an ordinal, not a column name, so that'd need to be data.GetDateTime(data.GetOrdinal("Birth"))